# Understanding the Models and Relationships for Creating a Playlist in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, relationship

I'm using Rails 4.0 with SQLite3.

I have four models: User, Album, Song, Playlist. I want users to be able to browse a list of songs and add them to one of their playlists. I can't seem to manipulate these relationships to get the data I want (for example, showing the playlists on a page or query them via rails console).

So far my model relationships look like so:

```
class Playlist < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :songs
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :playlists
end 

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :songs
end

class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :album
end
```

**Is this the wrong construction of this relationship?** I'm just trying to add songs to a user's playlist, display those playlists on the users profile and allow the user to view each unique playlist.

In troubleshooting for my own solutions, I'm getting an error in the rails console: `undefined method val for Arel:Nodes` when I try to execute `user.playlists.create(my_params_here)` to test the relationships. It begins to create the list, but then rolls it back with this error.

All insights are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your solution seems very adequate. The problem you are getting seems to be about missing foreign keys somewhere in your database schema. Could you show your sqlite tables?

Comment: I think you're right, but that's unexpected. [Here's the link to the schema](http://pastebin.com/NPAEfTkB). I assumed Rails created these associations automatically (foreign keys included). Which keys do I need to make in these relationships?

Comment: I don't think it's to do with your relationships, you're passing 'val' into that hash somewhere and it doesn't like it. Perhaps you mean it to be a string not a variable?

Comment: It is a missing foreign key -> https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/78bd18a90992e3da767cfe492f1bc5d63077da8a

Comment: Looking at your schema, your `playlist` table is missing a `user_id` foreign key. Also, your `playlist` table has a string column named `song`, which is probably not what you want; having a `song_id` foreign key is probably not what you want either, as a playlist should be able to have many songs. See my answer for a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think that a playlist and song would have a *many-to-many* relationship, since a playlist could have many songs and a song could belong to many playlists. In that case you should create a [`has-many :through` association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).

```
class Playlist < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :playlist_songs
  has_many :songs, through: :playlist_songs
end

class PlaylistSong < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :playlist
  belongs_to :song
end

class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :album
  has_many :playlist_songs
  has_many :playlists, through: :playlist_songs
end
```

You can generate the models and their relationships using the Rails model generator:

```
rails g model playlist user:references:index
rails g model song album:references:index
rails g model playlist_song playlist:references:index song:references:index
```

Note: you'll probably want to destroy your `playlist` and `song` models before running the above commands:

```
rails d model playlist
rails d model song
```

If that is not an option for you, then you'll need to create migrations for adding the relationships.

From your console:

```
user = User.create(username: "bob", password: "password", email: "a@b.com")
album = Album.create
song = Song.create(album: album)
playlist = user.playlists.create
PlaylistSong.create(playlist: playlist, song: song)
```

Comment: This makes a certain amount of sense, but this is part of where I initially had issues and just started over. This doesn't attach those playlists to the user when I run the relationships in rails console. I can create playlists just fine, but it's not giving any ownership of them to the users. Should user be part of the playlist_songs join table?

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be part of the join table, since the `playlist` of a `playlist_song` record is associated to a `user`. See my updated answer on how to create this records from the console.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this still isn't working. I'm wondering if it has something to do with the foreign keys mentioned earlier (perhaps one is missing? I'm using the same relationships in your OP plus the one for my `user` in the OP). When I create a playlist from the test site, it creates it. If I then go to the rails console to list the playlists of a particular user (`user.playlists`), it will not return any playlists for the user even though they created some. However, querying `Playlist.all` shows all of the playlists created so far. So the relationship doesn't appear to be there.

Comment: Also, try reloading your console if you haven't restarted it: `reload!`

Comment: Ah, I found an error on my end. I forgot to update the controller (it was still set to make a generic `Playlist.create` playlist, not a `user.playlist.create` list). Fixed it and working. Thanks for taking the time to explain this. As an aside, are there advantages to using polymorphic associations here as suggested below by Joe?

Comment: Thank you so much, I felt I was pretty comfortable with relations but this was a nightmare. You just saved my whole weekend lol

Comment: I was missing the middle table (PlaylistSongs).. I've done it a bunch of times but for some reason I forgot.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need a polymorphic association for songs. (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

First, you need to add two attributes, one an integer and one a string, to your Song table. Let's say, `:songable_id, :integer` and `:songable_type, :string`.

Then, the `:songable_type` would refer to the model `song` is associated with, and `:songable_id` would specify the instance of that model. So a `song` with `songable_type: "Playlist"` and `songable_id: 1` would refer to `Playlist.find(1)`.

Here's how you would set up the models:

```
class Playlist < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :songs, as: :songable
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :playlists
end 

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :songs, as: :songable
end

class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :songable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Comment: Very interesting, didn't know about this feature. Thanks a lot for suggesting it. I think I'll play around with it.

Comment: No problem. I've found it to be way easier to implement and manage than the traditional format. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Add your foreign keys as mentioned [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#foreign-keys)

As @JordanDedels commented it has to do with the foreign keys. If you can afford to upgrade Rails to the latest version. Instead of getting:

`undefined method val for Arel:Nodes`

You would get something like:
`ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'user_id' for Playlist.`